# Etiquette for casting close vote in the close votes review queue for a question that I already answered

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-close

Earlier today [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15908353/variable-sc-might-not-have-been-initalized) came up and I answered it.  Then recently I went to the Close Votes Review page and starting browsing questions to close.  That same question showed up in my close votes review queue.

What is the proper etiquette / proper action to take here, when a question I already answered shows up in the close votes review queue for me to vote on?

- If I vote to close as "Too Localized", as 3 others have done as of this post, or any other reason for that matter, then that seems silly, because why would I close a question I answered?
- If I vote to "Keep Open", that seems like a conflict of interest on my part, keeping it open because I answered it.  Or is it okay to "Keep Open", because I didn't think this question should have been closed when I answered it?
- I don't think using "Edit" to edit the question would be appropriate for this particular question.
- Should I just recuse myself and "Skip" the close vote for the question?

Comment: As for me, my implementation of "vote to close" process and "answer" process are separate, so I would answer AND vote to close if the question somehow meets my own criteria for both. :P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're answering a question you think should be closed, you're doing it wrong. If you think the question should be open, answering is of course correct. If you think it should be closed, don't answer it at all.

Of course there might be cases where you change your mind, but in general you should either answer or vote to close, and not both.

I don't see this as a conflict of interest, if you answered the question you should be convinced that it is a reasonable question that should stay open, and voting in review that way would be the correct course of action.

Answer (score 4):

If you felt the question was not too localized when you answered it, *has anything changed to make you change your mind*?

If not, then vote not to close, as it would seem you disagree with that close reason.

Answer (score 4):

> If I vote to "Keep Open", that seems like a conflict of interest on my part, keeping it open because I answered it. Or is it okay to "Keep Open", because I didn't think this question should have been closed when I answered it?

Conflict of interest?  No, of course not.  You *answered* it because you thought it was a good question.  If a few close votes make you think about it more carefully then it's fine to vote to close - shows some inconsistency on your part but also a willingness to admit when wrong and either way is fully within the bounds of a usual day on SO.  But if you still feel that it's an acceptable question, it's *not* a conflict of interest, it's you using your own judgment to further high quality Q&A on SO and you should act on that.